# Der Ausdruck "bei jemandem einschlagen wie eine Bombe"

Tags: meaning

Ein Zeitungausschnitt von [MOP.de](http://mobil.mopo.de/hsv/hsv-fans-flehen-didi--hol--uns-ivica-olic-zurueck,23481658,29679380.html)

> Ivica Olic zurück zum HSV? Diese Nachricht `schlug` bei den Fans der Rothosen am Dienstagnachmittag `ein wie eine Bombe`. In den MOPO-Kommentaren, auf Twitter und Facebook flehen sie: „Didi, hol' uns Ivica zurück!“

Was bedeutet `bei jmdm einschlagen wie eine Bombe` in diesem Kontext?

> The news hit the Rothosen fans like a bomb on Tuesday afternoon.

Ist meine Übersetzung dafür richtig?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was macht eine einschlagende Bombe? 
-> Verwirrung, Durcheinander, Aufruhr. Großer Eindruck. Manchmal Zerstörung.

Im Grunde kann man den Ausdruck wörtlich nehmen, man sollte aber beachten, dass in diesem bildlichen Gebrauch nicht notwendigerweise ein destruktiver Aspekt enthalten ist. Eine Nachricht, die "einschlägt wie eine Bombe" kann durchaus etwas Positives sein. Aber sie ist immer unerwartet, überraschend und von einer gewissen Tragweite; meist kündigt sie eine grundlegende Veränderung (oder die Erwartung einer Veränderung) an.

Beispiele für "positive Bomben":

- Ein Ehepaar erwartet nach vielen ungewollt kinderlosen Jahren plötzlich Nachwuchs.
- Ein bislang unbekannter Erbonkel vermacht einem Erben ein Vermögen.
- Das alte Bild aus Omas Schlafzimmer entpuppt sich als echter Rembrandt.

"Negative Bomben": siehe die Nachrichten....

Comment: Danke! Ich habe immer noch viel zu lernen.